# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Install Problem

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb-installation

PC Specs:
HP Pavilion Slimline S3200N
AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4800+ x2
Gallium 0.4 on NV4C
64-bit install off Live USB
2.3 GB RAM installed (with a full 4GB upgrade in the mail)
312GB disk space

Previously ran Win7, but this was my father's PC and was pretty hosed. Who knows what virus partially paralyzed it, but it was just not "quite right". Looks like he had someone reinstall Win7 as there was a windows.old file.

Problems I know exist:

- No internet connection
  *Integrated Ralink 802.11 bg WLAN is not compatible with my router, which I've set to only broadcast 802.11n (although it can still see it?)
  *Add-on wireless-n USB dongle Realtek 802.11n adapter doesn't seem to be able to connect (was intermittent before Ubuntu install), perhaps a driver issue?
- OS essentially freezes after bootup. Sometimes it's fairly quick, right now it seems to be holding together for a couple minutes (new record!)

Finally got an error report:
"Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error."
-Package linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic 3.19.0-25.26~ 14.04.1[modified: boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic][origin: unknown]
-ProblemType KernelOops
-Title BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffc9000492c000
-Annotation Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
-ApportVersion 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11
-Architecture amd64
-Date (rando date a couple days ago when I installed)
-Dependencies (WHOLE BUNCH)
-Failure oops
-InstallationMedia Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS "Trusty Tahr" -Beta amd64(20150805)

...etc.

Could this be a video card error? Have to do with the flaky wifi issue?  I would be fine killing wifi (for now) and running this as a standalone.  In fact, I tried to install it without networking, but it seems to really want to connect to wifi...

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever run a memory check (an option on the install media)?